# Vim scp undo clears file

Tags: undo-redo

When I open up a file remotely using `scp` (and possibly other protocols), running the `undo` command (right away, or repeatedly if I've made edits) clears the file. Why does this happen - is it a bug?

My guess is that it is a quirk of how remote editing is implemented - like Vim is actually opening a new local file, and then the first `change` is to copy all the text of the remote file into the new file.

Comment: There's a manual not-perfect workaround  - to exec `:set undoreload=0 | edit` once file is open. This cut the undo history. I however could not make it exec automatically with `autocmd`. Tried `autocmd EVENT scp://* :set undoreload=0 | edit` with EVENT either of BufRead BufEnter BufFilePost.

Answer (score 1):

Vim is using `netrw` to enable transparent remote file editing, see `:h scp`.

Try running `:set modified?` before and after `:undo`, you will see that a temporary buffer (probably stored locally) is created, then the content is fetched and written by the plugin.

It is not a perfect user experience but I guess it's how it works !

Comment: Is it to be understood as "there's nothing you can do about it" ?

Comment: @TagWint as far as I know, yes. I think you can restore the last version of the file using `:e!`.